# Visually Display Database Information with PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, select

I'm looking for a way to visually display my users' (schedules) at a glance.

This is what my tables essentially look like:

```
users:
   usrID     usrFirst     usrLast   etc..
     22        John         Doe

semesters:
   id      name      year
     1     Spring    2009

 class_info:
    id      name            building           room
     1      Economics         Carter            205
     2      Math              Carter            211

  class_data
    id        classID       usrID     semesterID       start             end      dow
     1         1             22           1           08:00:00        09:20:00     1
     2         1             22           1           08:00:00        09:20:00     3
     3         2             22           1           13:20:00        14:50:00     2
     4         2             22           1           13:20:00        14:50:00     4
```

So, what I'm trying to accomplish, (based on the example above) is to be able to see "blocked" times, visually, in a table.  Somewhat like this:

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | 08:00 | 09:00 | 10:00 | 11:00 | 12:00 | 1:00 | 2:00 | 3:00 | 4:00 | 5:00 |
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------      
Mon xxxxxxxxxx

Tue                                          xxxxxxxxxxxx

Wed xxxxxxxxxx

Thu                                          xxxxxxxxxxxx

Fri
```

Obviously, I'd probably like to use some type of image to show, and perhaps some type of grid on the table to make it easy to differentiate the times.

I'm not sure how to get started on this, and what to use.

Any ideas on how I'd need to get this going with my current DB structure?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Uhm. Just use PHP to output an HTML table? Or did I miss something here?

Comment: Yeah, but how would I query the database to show the "blocked" times based on the query?  In other words, the 'xxxx' in the above example display the 'classes' that are in use.  Sorry if I'm being a bit vague--kind of hard to communicate what's in my head sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Your database tables holds only the time but not the day. Please add the days into your database. I may help you in this issue.

Comment: Looks like class_data.dow holds the day of the week.